# Play framework 2.0 does not compile when using java.utils.Stack

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have this strange problem where any call to said data structure will give a nullPointerException when instantiated as a Stack, but not when instantiated as a List.

Both unit tests and running the play web server give nullPointerException when I run it with the stack class

This works:

```
....

/*
 * comment belongs to post, and if post is deleted,
 * the deletion is relayed to all comments that post object
 * owns
 */
@OneToMany (mappedBy="post",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Comment> comments;

....

public Post(SuperUser author,String content,String title){
    this.comments = new LinkedList<Comment>();
    this.author = author;
    this.content = content;
    this.title = title;
    this.postedAt = new Date();

}

...

public Post addComment(Comment newComment){
    this.comments.add(newComment);
    this.save();
    return this;
}
```

This does not work:

```
....

/*
 * comment belongs to post, and if post is deleted,
 * the deletion is relayed to all comments that post object
 * owns
 */
@OneToMany (mappedBy="post",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Stack<Comment> comments;

....

public Post(SuperUser author,String content,String title){
    this.comments = new Stack<Comment>();
    this.author = author;
    this.content = content;
    this.title = title;
    this.postedAt = new Date();

}

...

public Post addComment(Comment newComment){
this.comments.push(newComment); // ERROR
    this.save();
    return this;
}
```

I tried writing a wrapper interface for the List interface and giving it the method:

```
public E push(E elem);
```

But that does also not work.

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: What line are you getting the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Any call which referenced the Stack object. In this case it is adding to the list in the addComment(...) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not use concrete classes as the type of entity associations. Only interfaces: List, Set, Map. The ORM uses its own concrete implementations of these interfaces to implement dirty checking, lazy loading, etc.

Relevant quote from the spec:

> Collection-valued persistent fields and properties must be defined in terms of one of the following collection-valued interfaces regardless of whether the entity class otherwise adheres to the JavaBeans method conventions noted above and whether field or property access is used: java.util.Collection, java.util.Set, java.util.List, java.util.Map. The collection implementation type may be used by the application to initialize fields or properties before the entity is made persistent. Once the entity becomes managed (or detached), subsequent access must be through the interface type.

Comment: As stated in my post I tried a wrapper interface with no success.
Furthermore, it neither works with the Queue or Dequeue interfaces.

Does that mean I can ONLY use there 4 interfaces? How am I supposed to build a stack object if I cant even extend the interfaces? :(

Comment: Yes, you're restricted to these 4 interfaces. How would the ordering of elements in the stack be stored in the database anyway?

Comment: Its not about the database. It would be a lot easier to manipulate the comments in the html templates if they were stored in a stack type object, since the last comment in, is the first I want to display. 

At least now I know what the issue is.
Thanks!
(So much for "high velocity" framework)

Comment: JPA is an ORM. It gets/stores the information from/to the database, and can't magically guess how the comments must be ordered if you don't tell it. Stack is obsolete anyway, and List can be used to stored ordered or sorted elements. If you don't realize there is a database behind the entities, and dn't understand what JPA does to load and store entities in the database, you'll have problems.

Comment: Yes I am absolutely new to web-development / play framework. At least now I have a better understanding of JPA! thanks again!